# Taylor series in complex analysis -- change base point

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, power-series, taylor-expansion

Develop $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n $$ in a Taylor series, around $z=a$ with $|a|<1.$ What is the new radius of convergence?

**Solution.**
Now i think this is a "clitche", but i know that $$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z^n $$ for $|z|<1.$ Now if i take $$ \frac{1}{1-z} =  \frac{1}{1-a} \, \frac{1}{1-\frac{z-a}{1-a}} = \frac{1}{1-a} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z-a}{1-a}\right)^n $$ for $|\frac{z-a}{1-a}|<1$, so $|z-a|<|1-a|$ is the new radius of convergence. Is it right? Cause i'm a little confused. Is this the representation of an analytic function in that disk? Is the analytic continuation of the original function? i had never learn this in a simple words. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Almost.  The series begins at $n=0$

Comment: @Dr.MV How is that affect my result?

Comment: It affects the result in that the series as written, does not represent $(1-z)^{-1}$.  Other than this mistake, everything else is fine.

Comment: @Dr.MV so, replace $\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $\frac{z}{1-z}$ and the rest still remains (with that little adjust)

Comment: Yes, or replace $n=1$ with $n=0$

Answer (score 1):

The power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ defines an analytic function in the disk $D(0,1)$ which *extends* to $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\} $. Therefore, this function can be expressed as a power series around any $a\in\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$, and its radius of convergence is exactly the distance of $a$ from $1$. Indeed
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{1-a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z-a}{1-a}\right)^n\!,
$$
for every $z\in D(a,|1-a|)$.